# REST call inside proxy

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am having a proxy configuration for network because I am working for organization.

I am not able to make REST calls from java same work through rest client like postman etc on crome but from java its failing.I have set proxy in eclipse.Please find my code below.Any idea how to access REST services inside a proxy

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "http://xyz.com");

            //getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                   + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     }
```

Exception

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xyz.com refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.mkyong.rest.RestClient2.main(RestClient2.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What's the error/exception?

Comment: If that address is local, you should enable proxy bypassing (using eclipse configuration) for internal addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your `HttpClient` to use proxy.
Check http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e473

Sth like:
`httpClient..getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);`